# Proofs of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^n}=\int_0^1 \frac{1}{x^x}dx$

Tags: integration, summation

Prove that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^n}=\int_0^1 \frac{1}{x^x}dx$. This comes from this question [Evaluate $\sum_0^\infty \frac{1}{n^n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/703812/evaluate-sum-0-infty-frac1nn).

Comment: I agree. It's a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This identity is called Sophomore's dream (a "dream" because it seems too good to be true, and at the same time an identity because it is indeed true!).

It's proof can be found in Pedro Tamaroff's answer [to this related (actually, its exactly the same) question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/237513/series-as-an-integral-sophomores-dream).